Defining the Ricci tensor on a hermitian manifold
The following is an excerpt from a set of notes I'm following.

Let $M$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$ and let $g$ be an Hermitian structure in $T M$. It is called an Hermitian metric on $M$. A complex manifold $M$ with an Hermitian metric $g$ is called an Hermitian manifold. Then we can write$$ \begin{equation*}
g=\sum g_{i \bar{j}} d z^{i} d \bar{z}^{j}, \quad \text { where } \quad g_{i \bar{j}}=g\left(\partial / \partial z^{i}, \partial / \partial \bar{z}^{j}\right) \tag{1.7.7}
\end{equation*}
$$ (Following the tradition, we write $d z^{i} d \bar{z}^{j}$ instead of $d z^{i} \otimes d \bar{z}^{j}$ ). Let $D$ be the Hermitian connection of $g$. Let $R$ be the curvature of $D$; it is in $A^{1,1}(\operatorname{End}(T M))$. In terms of the frame field $\left(\partial / \partial z^{1}, \cdots, \partial / \partial z^{n}\right)$ and its dual $\left(d z^{1}, \cdots, d z^{n}\right)$, the curvature can be expressed as $$
\begin{equation*}
R=\sum \Omega_{j}^{i} d z^{j} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z^{i}}, \quad \text { where } \quad \Omega_{j}^{i}=\sum R_{j k \bar{h}}^{i} d z^{k} \wedge d \bar{z}^{h} \tag{1.7.8}
\end{equation*}
$$ Expressing (1.4.13) in terms of local coordinates, we have $$
\begin{equation*}
R_{j a \bar{b}}^{i}=-\sum g^{i \bar{k}} \frac{\partial^{2} g_{j \bar{k}}}{\partial z^{a} \partial \bar{z}^{b}}+\sum g^{i \bar{k}} g^{p \bar{q}} \frac{\partial g_{p \bar{k}}}{\partial z^{a}} \frac{\partial g_{j \bar{q}}}{\partial \bar{z}^{\theta}} \tag{1.7.9}
\end{equation*}
$$ If we set $$
\begin{equation*}
R_{j \bar{k} a \bar{b}}=\sum g_{i \bar{k}} R_{j a \bar{b}}^{i} \tag{1.7.10}
\end{equation*}
$$ then (1.7.9) reads as follows: $$
\begin{equation*}
R_{j \bar{k} a \bar{b}}=-\frac{\partial^{2} g_{j \bar{k}}}{\partial z^{a} \partial \bar{z}^{b}}+\sum g^{p \bar{q}} \frac{\partial g_{p \bar{k}}}{\partial z^{a}} \frac{\partial g_{j \bar{q}}}{\partial \bar{z}^{b}} \tag{1.7.11}
\end{equation*}
$$ We define two Hermitian tensor fields contracting the curvature tensor $R$ in two different ways. We set $$
\begin{gather*}
R_{k \bar{h}}=\sum R_{i k \bar{h}}^{i}=\sum g^{i \bar{j}} R_{i \bar{j} k \bar{h}}, \quad R i c=\sum R_{k \bar{h}} d z^{k} \otimes d \bar{z}^{h}  \tag{1.7.12}\\
K_{i \bar{j}}=\sum g^{k \bar{h}} R_{i \bar{j} k \bar{h}}, \quad \hat{K}=\sum K_{i \bar{j}} d z^{i} \otimes d \bar{z}^{j} \tag{1.7.13}
\end{gather*}
$$

I have two questions.

Does the author here have an unconventional way of defining the Ricci tensor? From the looks of it, they seem to define it as the contraction of the last two indices $j$ and $i$ in $$R^i_{jkl} dz^k \wedge d\bar{z}^l\otimes dz^j \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$$ which would differ from the standard using the first and last index.
Why isn't $\hat{K}$ identically zero given the symmetries of $R$?



The author may be leaving some details out. There are four ways to contract the curvature form of a Hermitian metric and get a tensor: contract the 1st and 2nd index, the 1st and 4th, the 3rd and 2nd, or the 3rd and 4th. These end up giving four different tensors in general (mostly; two will be conjugates of each other). Complex geometers mostly work with the tensors we get from contracting the 1st and 2nd or 3rd and 4th indices. One is the negative of the curvature form of the metric on the canonical bundle, and I believe the other has some nice analytic properties that let us prove versions of the Schwarz lemma. If we have a Kahler metric the curvature form has extra symmetries so all of these end up being equal, and then we get the familiar Ricci tensor from Riemannian geometry.

For a Hermitian metric the only symmetries of $R$ are that $\overline{R_{ijkh}} = -R_{jihk}$ (the minus because the author doesn't multiply his $(1,1)$-forms by $i$). This doesn't force $\hat K$ to be zero (check it for $n = 1$).


Maybe you're thinking of Hermitian metrics as Riemannian metrics and that's where the confusion comes from. There is a difference: the Hermitian curvature form is defined by the Chern connection, which is different from the Levi-Civita connection, so the two curvature forms are different and have different symmetries. Even for Kahler metrics, where the Chern connection has no torsion, the complex structure yields different symmetries for the curvature form than in the Riemannian case.

Thank you, I was indeed having some confusion with the Riemannian case.
